# How to change indexes in array with sub arrays with subarray property value in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, indexing

I need help. I have an array of items like this one:

```
[7646] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [id] => 156153
                [tmplvarid] => 5
                [value] => 2
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [id] => 56795
                [tmplvarid] => 7
                [value] => 430
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [id] => 56798
                [tmplvarid] => 19
                [value] => rate_08
            )
    ),
[7647] => Array ()
```

And I need to change array indexes to value of property **tmplvarid** in sub array to transform array like this:

```
`[7646] => Array
    (
        [5] => Array
            (
                [id] => 156153
                [tmplvarid] => 5
                [value] => 2
            )

        [7] => Array
            (
                [id] => 56795
                [tmplvarid] => 7
                [value] => 430
            )

        [19] => Array
            (
                [id] => 56798
                [tmplvarid] => 19
                [value] => rate_08
            )
    )
```

How can I transform it in assosiative array ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set index value from array value using `foreach loop`

**Code**

```
<?PHP
  $arr = [
    "7646" => array
    (
        [
           
                "id"=> 156153,
                "tmplvarid" => 5,
                "value" => 2
            
        ],
        [
           
                "id"=> 56795,
                "tmplvarid" => 7,
                "value" => 430
            
        ],
        [
           
                "id"=> 56798,
                "tmplvarid" => 19,
                "value" => "rate_08"
            
        ]
    )
];
echo "<pre>";
print_r($arr);
$newarr= [];
foreach($arr as $key => $value)
{
    foreach($value as $key1 => $value1)
    {
        $newarr[$key][$value1['tmplvarid']] = $value1;
    }
}
print_r($newarr);
?>
```

**Output**

```
Array
(
    [7646] => Array(
        [5] => Array
        (
            [id] => 156153
            [tmplvarid] => 5
            [value] => 2
        )
        [7] => Array
        (
            [id] => 56795
            [tmplvarid] => 7
            [value] => 430
        )
        [19] => Array
        (
            [id] => 56798
            [tmplvarid] => 19
            [value] => rate_08
        )
    )
)
```